# List Comprehension Python

Tags: python

This is the background code for the question:

```
class CourseList(object):

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number
        self.students = []
        print('In constructor of course list.')
    def addStudent(self, who):
        if not who.isStudent():
            raise TypeError('Not a student')
        if who in self.students:
            raise ValueError('Duplicate student')
        self.students.append(who)
    def remStudent(self, who):
        try:
            self.students.remove(who)
        except:
            print (str(who) + ' not in ' + self.number)
    def allStudents(self):
        return self.students

        #for s in self.students:
            #yield s
            #print (s)
    def ugs(self):
        indx = 0
        while indx < len(self.students):
            if type(self.students[indx]) == UG:
                yield self.students[indx]
            indx += 1


sixHundred = CourseList('6.00') 

sixHundred.addStudent(ug1)

sixHundred.addStudent(g1)

sixHundred.addStudent(ug2)
```

Code1:

```
for x in sixHundred.allStudents():

    print(x.__str__())
```

OUTPUT:

```
Jane Doe
Mitch Peabody
John Doe
```

Code2

```
print( (x.__str__() for x in sixHundred.allStudents() ) )
```

OUTPUT:

```
generator object genexpr at 0x000000000448C048
```

QUESTION: Why does the print statement with the list comprehension(CODE 2) not work?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to loop over your generator and print the values of it to see the values you're expecting

Comment: 1. That's not a list comprehension, as you're lacking `[` and `]`. 2. It does work, as written - you're seeing the resulting object from your generator expression.

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension with round braces creates a generator which you have in result.
You should use square brackets instead:

```
print([x.str() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()])
```

And if you want to get the same result as in code 1, type:

```
print(' '.join([x.str() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()]))
```

Comment: Actually, you need to use a newline seperator: `'\n'.join([x.str() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()])`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the list function with the generator to create a list of the strings:

```
print(list(x.__str__() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()))
```

Also, you can create a list with the brackets:

```
new_list = [x.__str__() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()]
```

Comment: Or `print([x.__str__() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()])`

Comment: Kinda defeats the purpose of converting it to a generator if it was originally a list

Comment: Why create the entire list in memory? I agree with @AK47, this really defeats the purpose of using a generator expression. Just iterate over the generator: `for name in (x.__str__() for x in sixHundred.allStudents()): print(name)`.